# Cordova build ios with buildConfig ask me password for codesign

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, codesign

I try to automate the build of my cordova application only on command line but when I try to build my ios application with buildConfig to sign it, I have a form that appears with "codesign wants to sign with the "mykey" key of your keychain".

Except that I don't want any display because it must be able to run without human, so everything is command line only.

I'm trying to unlock my keychain with

```
security unlock -p "my password" ~/Library/keychain/login.keychain-db
```

and

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k keychainPass keychainName
```

And I see the unlocked padlock on my key ring forms but when I re-launch my construction order, the coding form appears again.

Anyone know how to get around that prompt?

P.S: My build command is:
cordova build ios --device --release --buildConfig MyJSONPath.json